# Different menu icons for Android Honeycomb and above

Tags: android, android-resources, android-drawable

In my application I use light Action Bar in which I place icons of menu items. So, these icons are black, but in Android Gingerbread (and lower) menus are displayed in black background. I need to use a white version of the icons in that case. I placed white icons in `res/drawable` and black icons in `res/drawable-v11`:

```
└── res
    ├── drawable
    │   ├── ic_action_auth.png
    │   ├── ic_action_refresh.png
    │   └── ic_action_web.png
    └── drawable-v11
        ├── ic_action_auth.png
        ├── ic_action_refresh.png
        └── ic_action_web.png
```

Running my app in a Jelly Bean emulator, icons are correctly displayed in black (so `drawable-v11` is used, as expected). **But in the Gingerbread emulator, icons are displayed in black too, and I can't get why.** I don't know what details I can give you more. This is one of the menus I created, the single version of the resource `res/menu/menu.xml`:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@id/action_refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/action_refresh"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_auth"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_auth"
        android:orderInCategory="101"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/auth"
        android:titleCondensed="@string/auth_condensed">
    </item>

</menu>
```

Comment: Hmm this is weird. Are you completely sure, that the icons in your drawable folder are actually light icons? Maybe you mixed something up.

Comment: @Ahmad Yes, look here: http://i.imgur.com/QNo3kd4.png

Comment: @Ahmad I tried *Eclipse > Project > Clean...* and *Rebuild* and now it's fine. Looks like builder messed something up, probably *Refreshing* the project after created the resources alternatives was not enough.

Comment: Ah ok. Good to hear that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making another drawable folder: `res/drawable-hdpi-v11`

Another option would be to use ActionBarSherlock so your app can have an ActionBar on older versions of Android. That's what I would recommend, personally.

Comment: I created `res/drawable-hdpi-v11` and tested it with light icons and black icons too. Nothing has changed :(

Comment: I tried *Eclipse > Project > Clean...* and *Rebuild* and now it's fine. Looks like builder messed something up, probably *Refreshing* the project after created the resources alternatives was not enough.